# Parsing soap wsdl java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I can't parse soap request wsdl file. I have xml file from soapui
(soapui-project.xml) and in this file data id and name

```
<types>
 <xsd:schema>
  .......
 </xsd:schema>
 </type>....
...<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<!-Optional:-->
<idNumber>123</idNumber>
<name>abc</name>...
```

I try with code with java :

```
 public SOAPMessage readSoapMessage(String xmlInput) throw SOAPException, FileNotFoundException{
         SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
         SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
          soapPart.setContent(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(xmlInput)));
          message.saveChanges();
          return message;
}
SOAPMessage message = readSoapMessage(xmlInput);
message.writeTo(System.out);
```

But i get all xml file i need get only idNumber and name. How i can do that?
Thank you

Comment: Is there any specific reason why do you parse SoapUi project file? It is possible, but you need to understand the SoapUI object model. If you describe more in detail what you need to achieve, there can be a simpler solution.

Comment: ok,Yes i want chek data before i send request. i have xml from projec in soapui, i need check id number  in this xml before i'm runing soapui

Comment: If you need to check the data before sending a request from SoapUI, then you can check the data from SoapUI, without parsing the project file. You can access the request xml with a Groovy script, e.g. with test case SetUp script.